# Problems with Push Queues on Google App Engine Managed VM / Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, google-managed-vm

I am having trouble with using Push Queues on Google App Engine's Flexible Environment (formally named, their Managed VM Environment). I am receiving numerous `404` `Instance Unavailable` (see picture below).

After a bit of sleuthing, I believe these errors may be because I am adding a task to a task queue, then deploying a new version of the Flexible VM instance. The taskqueue that I previously pushed is locked to the older instance, and can no longer run. Is this how taskqueues work with Flexible VM? If so, how does one use push taskqueues with the Flexible VM?

[image: taskqueue instance unavailable]

Answer (score 4):

I was 90% done migrating to flexible env when I came across this same problem. After extensive research, I concluded there are three options:

#### REST API (experimental)

Use the beta REST API for task queues (this, as all other google APIs from flexible env, is external, so you need to deal with auth appropriately).

REST API reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/

Note, this is external and experimental. Find e.g. a java sdk without any meaningful documentation here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/ (current version: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/taskqueue/v1beta2)

#### Compat runtime

Build your own flexible environment, based off a -compat runtime. This offers the old appengine api in a container suitable for the flexible env:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build (look for images with "YES" in the last column)

e.g.: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9-and-apis

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-an-existing-app

Note: I spent two weeks in blistered frustration pleading every God almighty help me get this to work, following container rabbit holes into the depths of Lucifer's soul and across unexplored dimensions. I eventually had to give in. I just can't get this to work to a satisfying degree.

#### Proxy service

Kind of a hacky alternative, but it gets the job done: create a very thin standard environment wrapper service which proxies tasks onto / off your queue. Pass them to your own app however you want. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Downside is you are now spinning up extra instances and burning extra minutes.

I ended up with a variation of this, where I'm using a proxy service in standard env, but just ported my eventual task handler to AWS Lambda (so it's completely off GAE). It's a different disaster, but a more manageable one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the tech lead and manager for this product.

There are two distinct answers to your question.

For the first, it seems like you have a version routing issue -- as you say, tasks cannot run against a VM because you launched a new version. By default, tasks are assigned to run on the version from which they were enqueued to avoid version mismatches. You should be able to override the version by re-configuring the target in your queue.yaml (or queue.xml). Documentation for that can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref). You might also need to look at your

From a broader perspective, building a migration path away from standard/MVM-only support for task queues is currently our highest priority.

The replacement is Cloud Tasks, which exposes the same interface but can be used fully independently from App Engine. It exists in the same universe as AppEngine Task Queues, so you will be able to add tasks to existing queues (both push and pull). It is currently available in closed alpha. You can sign up to join the alpha [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).

We strongly recommend against writing new code against the REST API. It is unsupported and the cloud tasks alpha is already substantially more feature complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm upvoting hraban's answer (he did wrestle with the devil after all) but providing an additional answer here.

Keep in mind that the Flexible Environment (Managed VMs) is still just a compute engine instance... with Google doing a good job of extracting features from AppEngine to make them reachable in a transparent manner.  TaskQueues didn't quite make it.  Keep a sharp eye on the cloud library--that's the mechanism by which the DataStore becomes usable (for Java go to http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.3.0/index.html).  If you go to that link you can also select other languages.  I have it on official word that TaskQueues are still on the roadmap (but no ETA).

As of now you **can't** use the REST api to enqueue onto PUSH queues.  Now the way that I decided to tackle this problem was to use the REST API and create a PULL queue to put tasks in.  Then I poll that queue inside an AppEngine service (i.e. module) and put it into a PUSH task queue.  Why do I go to all that trouble?  Because I need scheduled execution... which is a feature that TaskQueues alone can give you on AppEngine.  So I package my task in an envelope and then unpack and re-push it into a task queue.  Sounds crazy?  It's been working reliably for me.  Don't be scared off by the fact that the REST api is "alpha".

I will say if you're starting something new take a good look at the [Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/).